# AWS CLI EC2: option modify-default-credit-specification not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

It says in the EC2 userguide that you can change the t2/t3/t3a default-credit-specification for your AWS account [Link Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-how-to.html#burstable-performance-instance-set-default-credit-specification-for-account).
When I run the command `aws ec2 modify-default-credit-specification --region us-east-1 --instance-family t2 —-cpu-credits unlimited`, it says `Invalid choice: 'modify-default-credit-specification'`. How do I change the default specification of t2/t3/t3a instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your aws cli to the latest version.

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.14.44 Python/3.6.8 Linux/4.15.0-72-generic botocore/1.8.48
$ aws ec2 modify-default-credit-specification
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
...
```

but

```
$ ~/.local/bin/aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.309 Python/3.6.8 Linux/4.15.0-72-generic botocore/1.13.45
$ ~/.local/bin/aws ec2 modify-default-credit-specification
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: the following arguments are required: --instance-family, --cpu-credits
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will work in AWS CLI version 2.

Link to download/install -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-windows.html'

**Command to check default CPU Level credits:-**

aws ec2 --region us-west-2  get-default-credit-specification --instance-family t3

**Command to disable at account level for Oregon Region:**

aws ec2 modify-default-credit-specification --region us-west-2 --instance-family t3 --cpu-credits standard